# What are Echostones?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

So I recently discovered a few Echostones, however when I try to use them I get the message that it doesn't respond to my interaction.

So what purpose has the Echostones, and how can I use them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Echostones are merely "playback devices" - you'll normally have to find a stored song, usually in the shape of a ball, in order to get the Echostone to play something back.  These balls are called "cairns."

The one I'm most familiar with is the one in the Ballads Library, which gives you the quest "The Treasures of Meropis" - you'll find the stored song in the same area as the Echostone, lying on the floor.

Later during the Fae faction questline, you'll need to recover several of these and solve a short puzzle based on their contents.

Answer (score 1):

Echostones are used to get quests,you have to have Fae Cairn (green ball-shaped lorestone) which you can find in various locations in the game.

Once you interact with Echostone you will be able to use any Fae Cairn you currently have in your inventory to start a ballad in form of a quest.